# Reflection matrix that reflects a given vector in ℝ3 with respect to the  -  plane

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know how to reflect across an axis with a 3x3 matrix, but I'm not quite sure how to reflect with respect to a plane. I believe the 3x3 matrix [-1,0,0],[0,-1,0],[0,0,1] works, but am not sure. Could someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\z_1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\-z_1\end{bmatrix}$$A bit more clallenging is to find the matrix tht corresponds to reflection across the plane $ax+by+cz=0$. Still more challenging would be the affine transformation corresponding to reflection across the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0.$